# How know chat id of group on Telegram without use /getUpdates?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, chatbot, php-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I created a bot and i want to send with it messages in a group where this bot wad added like an admin.

The problem is that i don't kno `chat ID` of grop and around the web i read only one method to extrapolate it:

```
 https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/getUpdates
```

but i don't want to use this method because i already use `WebHook` and when it is active i can't use `getUpdates`.

So do you know how can i solve my problem ?

Maybe is there a way to know groups and channels where there's m bot ?
Or maybe to know groups and channels of user where there's my bot like admin?

Other suggestions ?

Thanks a lot and sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

Clone this repository and insert your bot token inside the index.js as root folder. and run this project. When anything you will do with your bot, it will catch or subscribe all activity inside the index.js file. And there is one method call handle(), it's the default method of getting all.

https://github.com/kunvarsingh/telegram-chatbot.git

Comment: And if you have any problem, or queries then let ,me know here.